# How do I solve "the trait bound `[closure]: tokio::prelude::Future` is not satisfied" when calling tokio::spawn?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

```
extern crate tokio; // 0.1.22

use tokio::io;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio::prelude::*;

use bytes::Bytes; // 0.4.12

fn main() {
    let addr = "0.0.0.0:1502".parse().unwrap();
    let mut listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).unwrap();

    let done = listener
        .incoming()
        .map_err(|e| println!("failed to accept socket; error = {:?}", e))
        .for_each(move |socket| {
            let process = move || {};

            tokio::spawn(process)
        });

    tokio::run(done);
    Ok(());

    tokio::run(done);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[closure@src/main.rs:17:27: 17:37]: tokio::prelude::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:13
   |
19 |             tokio::spawn(process)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `tokio::prelude::Future` is not implemented for `[closure@src/main.rs:17:27: 17:37]`
   |
   = note: required by `tokio::spawn`
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9dbfa8a0918df9d1d261c2b9d18eb8dc))

Comment: There's clearly a question missing.

Comment: `tokio::spawn` expects `Future` as argument not a random closure. You might use `let process = futures::future::lazy(move || Ok(()));` to use closure as Future(which will be executed on it's first poll) but this depends on your requirement, what do you really want to achieve?  Please check [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77c6fe3ade55a3211aefc011f3634daf) and compare with yours

Comment: @ÖmerErden sounds like an answer to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the [definition of `tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/executor/fn.spawn.html):

```rust
pub fn spawn<F>(f: F) -> Spawn 
where
    F: Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + 'static + Send
```

It expects an implementation of `Future` as its argument. The closure you passed into `tokio::spawn` is not an implementation of `Future`. Instead of a closure, Futures-rs has [`lazy`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.29/futures/future/fn.lazy.html)

> Creates a new future which will eventually be the same as the one created by the closure provided.

Simply, a `lazy` future holds a closure to execute. This happens on the first execution of `poll` made by the executor (in this case you are using Tokio executor).

If you wrap your closure with `lazy`, your code will work as you expected.

```rust
extern crate tokio; // 0.1.22

use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let addr = "0.0.0.0:1502".parse().unwrap();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).unwrap();

    let done = listener
        .incoming()
        .map_err(|e| println!("failed to accept socket; error = {:?}", e))
        .for_each(move |_socket| {
            let process = futures::future::lazy(move || {
                println!("My closure executed at future");
                Ok(())
            });

            tokio::spawn(process)
        });

    tokio::run(done);
}
```